# Import and use debugout.js with an impact.js project

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I have an [impact.js](https://impactjs.com/) project deployed [here](https://dtnetwork.github.io/HPVGameNew/).
I am trying to install [debugout.js](https://github.com/inorganik/debugout.js) in the project. To do so, I downloaded the debugout.js file from the repo's [dist directory](https://github.com/inorganik/debugout.js/tree/master/dist) and copied it in the same folder as my main.js and called it in the index.html file as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/impact/impact.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/game/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/game/debugout.js"></script>
```

I also tried importing it directly in main.js as follows but it did not work either. How do I import the debugout file correctly in an impact project?

```
ig.module(
    'game.main'
)
.requires(
    'impact.game',
    'impact.font',
    'game.levels.level1mapped',
    'game.levels.level2mapped',
    'game.levels.level3mapped',
    'game.levels.level4mapped',
    'game.levels.level5mapped',
    'game.levels.select',
    'game.levels.leveltest',
    'plugins.camera',
    'plugins.touch-button'
    // 'game.debugout'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by creating a g lobal variable `var bugout = new debugout();` in a new file called `logger.js` and then importing the file in index.html

This allows me to use bugout inside the impact js files as follows and lets me log whatever I want to log: `bugout.log("initial log");`

Mission accomplished!